# How to display multiple controls in single activity in android

Tags: android

i want to display two listview and some other components in three different frames in single activity. Which layout should i use? 
Give me example for that.also give me various alternates

Comment: You can use any Layout.First read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and then use one of them. then ask here if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code. you can set its width and height as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvList1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvList2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Layout is the best one to use or you can relative layout.